# Problem regarding wifi bcm4313

Tags: drivers, wireless, 16.10, broadcom

I've had some troubles with my wifi using Ubuntu. It seems like I can't connect to modems set to a channel above 11. However I can connect to such modem in windows, therefore the problem must be related to ubuntu and to the driver provided for my `broadcom bcm4313`. I tried switching to the default driver instead of the one coming from the `bcmwl-kernel-source` which is the one I am running right now as you can see [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24360690/) but the problem persists. Previously I had jumped out of the problem setting the channel on 11, but I'd like to connect also to modems that don't necessarily rely on that channel and below, as I can do in windows. One more detail is that since I switched to brcmsmac I see this message when booting:

```
Support for cores revisions 0x17 and 0x18 disabled by module param allhwsupport=0. 
Try b43.allhwsupport=1.
```

Comment: and when you did try `b43.allhwsupport=1` as suggested what happend?

Comment: @Rinzwind I did not try it because it automatically stopped showing when switching to the bcmwl-kernel-source driver, and I wouldn't know how to try it since I don't know which file it refers to, I guess I might try but I didn't think it could be related with the driver capability of detecting the modem depending on what channel it is set on

Comment: I thought it wasn't an important message so it could be that I undehestimated it, but reading some article around I found that it was related to the b43 firmware, which some were arguing not to be compatible with bmc4313, so I didn't know what to do about it @Rinzwind

Comment: Time to alert the resident expert @chili555    He will know what to do :D

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is an issue with all broadcom modules and they seem to be limited to channels 1-11 in 2.4GHz

You might be able to use the patch at https://github.com/respeaker/openwrt/blob/master/package/kernel/mac80211/patches/850-brcmsmac-remove-extra-regulation-restriction.patch to patch the kernel source but it didn't work when I tried it with my BCM4313

Comment: Yes I've read posts stating the same, but can't be just the chip because I can see my connection in windows. What I will try is trying to install the driver I have in windows with wine, and then I'll see if it goes fine

Comment: I said modules as in the linux drivers is what prevents those channels from being used but broadcom could have put something in the firmware