# Why do I have to reboot to be connect to the wifi?

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop and nearly each time I open it I am unable to connect to the wifi. The wireless icon in the top menu is present but when I click on it no wireless networks are available. I have to reboot my computer and then it works perfectly well (automatic connection to a wifi network).

Why do I have to reboot? Is there a way to connect automatically without rebooting?

This problem occurs every time I suspend my computer. When I login after a standby I have no more internet connection and the only solution I found so far is to reboot...

Here is the output of `lspci` (I am now connected)

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
07:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
08:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 61)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

When I am not connected (after stand by) here are the outputs of some commands:

Output of `lsmod | grep iwl`

```
iwlmvm                311296  0
mac80211              737280  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              565248  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
```

Output of `rfkill list all`

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `lspci`

Comment: I just posted the output of `lspci`

Comment: When you boot and it is *not* working, is the driver loaded? `lsmod | grep iwl` Is the wireless radio switched on or off? `rfkill list all` Does restarting Network Manager help? `sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: Reboot is hardly ever needed. You can restart the service for wireless.  As @chili555 explained while I was typing this... Only kernel update ask for a reboot (but even that is not really needed). Chili555: did you see my pm from this week? >:) If not mind having a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/903550/problem-regarding-wifi-bcm4313#comment1417320_903550 too?

Comment: `sudo service network-manager restart` **seems** to solve the problem (a list of wireless networks appears under the wireless icon, but even if it said I am connected to one of them I am unable to access internet (`ping 8.8.8.8` shows 100% of packet loss). I posted the output of the commands you asked for.

Comment: @Rinzwind I tried to restart the service and it did not help, however when rebooting I connected automatically to the network. However I agree with you this should not be required, but I am still wondering how I should do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem (or at least a part of the problem). I was connected to a vpn (with openvpn) that appears not to work correctly. When I stopped the vpn connection (`sudo service openvpn stop`) all went well again.

I also restarted my vpn service on the server and I uncommented the line `AUTOSTART="none"` in `/etc/default/openvpn` on my computer.

However I still don't know why my computer connected to the vpn after suspending but not after reboot...

Comment: This works for me too! I already search why this happens. Most cases are cannot connect after suspend, but this is different. The culprit is openvpn.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing this in your terminal

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

and see if that works for you.

Comment: As I said it in the comments above, it makes wireless networks visible and the wireless icon seems to say I am connected to one of these networks. However I still have no internet connection (`ping 8.8.8.8` shows 100% packet loss) and rebooting is (as far as I know) the only way to get internet working...

Comment: my wife had a similar problem and the network-manager restart used to help. After she upgraded to 16.10 the problem has gone away. Not sure if the upgrade would solve it for you, but it did it for her.

Comment: it actually did something since the available wireless networks showed up, but did not properly connect to one of them