# Reboot needed to be able to connect to public WiFi portals

Tags: networking, kubuntu, dns

I've never been able to figure out why I could never connect to public WiFi networks using Kubuntu 18.04 (it also happened on 17.04). That is, until I figured out a restart does allow me to connect afterwards.

I am actually able to connect to the network usually, but the portal login fails to load because of apparent failed domain name resolution.

I found the following: [Why do I have to reboot to be connect to the wifi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904299/why-do-i-have-to-reboot-to-be-connect-to-the-wifi), on which they recommend restarting the network manager. This does not help. Neither does flushing the DNS cache.

This is driving me mad because otherwise it's almost never necessary to reboot. Any ideas?

EDIT
@heynnema:

```
riccardo@T480:~$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 342 mrt 21 09:04 /etc/resolv.conf
riccardo@T480:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
domain business.finl.fortis
nameserver 10.142.128.13
nameserver 10.142.210.10
nameserver 127.0.0.53
search *** publiek_internet
riccardo@T480:~$ resolvectl
resolvectl: command not found
riccardo@T480:~$ resolvectl
resolvectl: command not found
riccardo@T480:~$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
riccardo@T480:~$
```

Comment: Edit your question to show me `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `resolvectl` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Report back to @heynnema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem looks like somebody has modified the symlink for `/etc/resolv.conf`, and then manually edited this file. Lets recreate the original symlink. And DON'T edit `/etc/resolv.conf`!

`cd /etc` # change directory

`sudo mv resolv.conf resolv.conf.HOLD` # rename the file

`sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` # recreate symlink

Comment: I have to apologize, the *** string was done by me as some urls were displayed that I (and my employer) possibly did not want to be broadcasted to everyone. Other than that, it was a fresh install and the file was not manually edited (if at all).

Comment: sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches && sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved seems to do the trick for now. I didn't know I have to restart the dns service. I'll monitor it for a few days to confirm.

Comment: @riccardo_92 you totally lost me with the "*** string" part. You shouldn't have to flush caches and restart systemd-resolved. That just works around the real problem. My answer is at least a **part** of the real fix.

Comment: there's a part with *** in my cat /etc/resolve.conf output, which was manually edited. In any case, I'll try your suggestions and get back to you.

Comment: @riccardo_92 status please

Comment: @hennema: I could only test it today, at the office again. It now finally works without a restart.